# HTTP POST callout not showing response body

Tags: httpresponse, httppost

I am making a HTTP POST callout from Salesforce. I am getting a HTTP 200 response code from the remote server but I am not getting the response body in the response. However, when I am using the same request body to send the data from postman, I am getting the response body.

Here's the Salesforce code I am using:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();            
req.setMethod('POST');

req.setEndpoint('https://ZXXXXXXXX/api/ZXXXXXXXX');
String username = 'ZXXXXXXXX';
String password = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' +
EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

req.setBody(JSON.serialize(lstOfObjectIWantToSend));


System.debug('json serialized object: 
'+JSON.serialize(lstOfObjectIWantToSend));

HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);

System.debug('Response from Server in Salesforce: '+res);
```

I am using the reference code depicted here:  [How to make a post request to some other server from apex controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5182/how-to-make-a-post-request-to-some-other-server-from-apex-controller)

Am I doing something wrong here?

---

First Edit:
In the logs, I am printing the entire response object, this is what I see:

USER_DEBUG [50]|DEBUG|Response from Dynamics in Salesforce: System.HttpResponse[Status=OK, StatusCode=200]

Comment: Why are you saying you are not getting response? did you print the response body? Try to print res.getBody() and see what it prints.

Comment: @datasert I am not getting response body. I am getting only response code and response status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the response when I used res.getBodyAsBlob().toString();

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.When i try to use like above it saying argument cannot be null

Comment: Do System.debug() for all possible response methods. One of them should have a response.

Answer (score 0):

When you print the response object as is, Salesforce doesn't log the body as body could be huge. Try logging the body explicitly.

```
System.debug('Response from Server in Salesforce: '+res.getBody());
```

Comment: Since I wasnt getting anything in res.getBody() I printed the entire res object. But to my point, I am not getting res.getBody() even if I print it explicitly

Comment: If you already tried to print body, then Server you calling must be returning different response than when you post via Postman. Because of fundamental nature of http callouts, I don't think Salesforce would be any issue here. I would first try to proxy the call via some third party and see what shows up.

Comment: I got the response when I used res.getBodyAsBlob().toString()