# Apex Callout HTTP POST with Named Credentials error

Tags: apex, apex-webservice, httppost

I am constructing something wrong, in the POST request. Please advise.

**Step 1:** Created Named Credential called **Stock_Check_For_Materials**

**Step 2:** Created Apex Controller as below

```
Continuation con = new Continuation(40);
con.continuationMethod='processResponse';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:Stock_Check_For_Materials/stockcheck');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');  
req.setBody('customerNumber='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(cN, 'UTF-8')+'&requireGenericEquivalent='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(rGE, 'UTF-8')+'&itemNumber='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(itN, 'UTF-8')+'&orderQuantity='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(oQ, 'UTF-8'));
this.requestLabel = con.addHttpRequest(req);
```

Please note that the 'customerNumber', 'requireGenericEquivalent', 'itemNumber' and 'orderQuantity' are the POST body for request and cN,rGE,itN,oQ are the getter and setter variable values coming from the visualforce page to this controller.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a post request to some other server from apex controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5182/how-to-make-a-post-request-to-some-other-server-from-apex-controller)

Comment: @glls That is not an appropriate duplicate, as far as I can tell.

Comment: not quite sure what the op's issue is as is. ill wait a bit for an update

Comment: @glls application/json vs application/x-www-form-encoded, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've specified the `Content-Type` as `application/json`, but you're using a `application/x-www-form-encoded` encoding style. You need to make sure they agree with each other.

```
// These do not agree with each other
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req.setBody('customerNumber='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(cN, 'UTF-8')+'&requireGenericEquivalent='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(rGE, 'UTF-8')+'&itemNumber='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(itN, 'UTF-8')+'&orderQuantity='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(oQ, 'UTF-8'));
```

## Corrected

```
String jsonBody = JSON.serialize(
new Map<String, String> {
'customerNumber' => cN,
'requireGenericEquivalent' => rGE, 
'itemNumber' => itN,
'orderQuantity' => oQ});
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req.setHeader('Content-Length',jsonBody.length()+'');
req.setBody(jsonBody);
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfix -> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void size() from the type String at line 29 column 49 (This is the second last line)

Comment: @Sid Yes, you need to do it just like I posted in my answer.

Comment: @Sid Yeah, it should have been length, not size.

Comment: You are brilliant @sfdcfox

Comment: Need 1 more help, my endpoint is expecting JSON in this format
{
  "stock": {
    "accountInfo": {
      "customerNumber": "121",
      "requireGenericEquivalent": "Y"
    },
    "itemInfo": {
      "itemNumber": "121",
      "orderQuantity": "10"
    }
  }
}

What will be the right jsonBody please ?

Comment: @Sid You'll need to use a nested map for this, like `new map<string, object> { 'stock' => new map<string, object> { 'accountInfo' => new Map<String, Object> { 'customerNumber' => cN, 'requireGenericEquivalent' => rGE }, 'itemInfo' => new Map<String, String> { 'itemNumber' => itN, 'orderQuantity' => oQ } } };`

Comment: Not only you are brilliant, but also a great teacher, and someone to look up to! How can I buy you a coffee/drink?

Comment: @Sid Thanks for the compliment, I certainly appreciate it! I'm always rather embarrassed to accept any kind of gift, but I'd also not want to offend by turning down a minor gift, so if you'd like, you may contact me using the details on my user profile.